# jqGrid ASP.NET MVC2 DataBind NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying JQGrid ASP.NET MVC2 version.

Created a model and the controller:

```
    var itemsGridModel = new OrderItemsjqGridModel();
    itemsGridModel.OrderItemsGrid.DataUrl = Url.Action("ItemsDataRequested", new {OrderID = OrderID, CustomerID = CustomerID });
    orderVM.orderItemsGrid = itemsGridModel;


    return View(orderVM);
```

The ItemsDataRequested:

```
public JsonResult ItemsDataRequested(int OrderID, int CustomerID)
{
    // Get both the grid Model and the data Model

    var gridModel = new OrderItemsjqGridModel();
    var orderItems = ordersRepository.GetOrder(OrderID).ItemsInOrders.ToList();

    IQueryable<ItemsInOrder> myItems = orderItems.AsQueryable<ItemsInOrder>();

    return gridModel.OrderItemsGrid.DataBind(myItems);
}
```

I get a NullReferenceException in the last line. 
The myItems has 1 Item with all values filled.

**Any Idea what am I doing wrong ?**

Thanks.

StackTrace:

```
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.Util.PrepareJsonResponse(JsonResponse response, JQGrid grid, DataTable dt)
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.Util.ConvertToJson(JsonResponse response, JQGrid grid, DataTable dt)
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.JQGrid.FilterDataSource(Object dataSource, NameValueCollection queryString, IQueryable& iqueryable)
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.JQGrid.GetJsonResponse()
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.JQGrid.DataBind()
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.JQGrid.DataBind(Object dataSource)
   at TechRun.UI.Controllers.OrdersController.ItemsDataRequested(Int32 OrderID, Int32 CustomerID) in y:\work\yosi\source\Techrun\TechRun.UI\Controllers\OrdersController.cs:line 118
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Model:

```
public class OrderItemsjqGridModel
{
    public JQGrid OrderItemsGrid { get; set; }

public OrderItemsjqGridModel()
{            
    OrderItemsGrid = new JQGrid
                     {
                         Columns = new List<JQGridColumn>()
                         {
                             new JQGridColumn { DataField = "OrderID", 
                                                // always set PrimaryKey for Add,Edit,Delete operations
                                                // if not set, the first column will be assumed as primary key
                                                PrimaryKey = true,
                                                Editable = false,
                                                Width = 30 },
                             new JQGridColumn { DataField = "ItemID",
                                                PrimaryKey = true,
                                                Editable = true,
                                                Width = 120},
                             new JQGridColumn { DataField = "ItemDescription", 
                                                Editable = true,
                                                Width = 300},
                             new JQGridColumn { DataField = "NumOfItems", 
                                                Editable = true,
                                                Width = 50
                                                },
                             new JQGridColumn { DataField = "CostOfItem", 
                                                Editable = true,
                                                Width = 75 },
                             new JQGridColumn { DataField = "TotalCost",
                                                Editable =  false
                                              },
                             new JQGridColumn { DataField = "SuppolyDate", 
                                                Editable = true,
                                                Width = 120, 
                                                DataFormatString = "{0:d}" },
                         },
                         Width = Unit.Pixel(640),
                         Height = Unit.Percentage(100)
                     };

    OrderItemsGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowRefreshButton = true;
    OrderItemsGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowAddButton = true;
    OrderItemsGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowDeleteButton = true;
    OrderItemsGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowEditButton = true;
}

}
```

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, any luck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for a solution for the same problem with no luck, I have returned back to my code for more exception analysis, and I found the solution, I prefered to log it here so anybody has the same problem would be satisfied.

I have discovered the reason, the Model JGridColumn names are different than the returned SQL query fields, there was a spelling mistake in one of the the Model columns.

Make sure all JGrid columns' names are identical with the SQL query columns' names.

Comment: Hi Shadi, it is indeed an old question, I don't have the source any more, so I take you upon your word... I'll mark this as an answer, and if anyone will post here otherwise, re-evaluate :-)